# React Native Linking not allowing linked page to open native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am working on translating an app from a custom webview-like system to using react-native-webview.

One page sends the user to another company's page to log in and then redirects back to set up a device. Originally this was handled by creating and clicking on an invisible link, but on webview that opened the page inside the app, so now `Linking.openURL(url)` is being used so the page opens on the phone's browser.

The user is being sent to the page but after login they are not send back to my app. The following message appears in the console: `Navigation is blocked: myapp://accept?code=1234`

This behavior exists on both ios and android.

I have used `npx uri-scheme open` to ensure that the link it valid.

Changing the uri to use intent on android caused the playstore to open rather than the app.